# rank query in laravel from one table data

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, rank

At the moment it gets the races times in order but i want to combined the user_id column together, but to make sure when it groups it together it, the fastest recorded_time is kept.

Example of what i have so far from the query

```
 User_id | race_id | recorded_time | stroke | 
 __________________________________________
    2    |    2    |     10.03     |  fly   |
 ____________________________________________
    1    |    3    |     12.98     |  fly   |
 ____________________________________________
    2         3          13.58     |  fly   |
```

Here is the code that gives me that result

```
  $query->where('race_history.stroke', '=', $stroke)
        ->orderBy('recorded_time', 'ASC')->get();
```

This is what i want it to return

```
 User_id | race_id | recorded_time | stroke | 
 __________________________________________
    2    |    2    |     10.03     |  fly   |
 ____________________________________________
    1    |    3    |     12.98     |  fly   |
 ____________________________________________
```

I have tried the code bellow but it doesn't take the fastest record time

```
$query->where('stroke', '=', $stroke)
      ->orderBy('recorded_time', 'ASC')
      ->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

But Instead produces this

```
 User_id | race_id | recorded_time | stroke | 
 __________________________________________
    1    |    3    |     12.98     |  fly   |
 ____________________________________________
    2    |    3    |     13.58     |  fly   |
 ____________________________________________
```

So its grouping it by user_id BUT not taking it fastest recorded time

I have tried so many ways anyone can help this is a raw query to get what i want i would use this but the AND distance doesnt like this..

```
$total = DB::select(DB::raw('
    SELECT *, min(recorded_time) as time
    FROM race_history
    WHERE stroke = "' . $stroke . '" AND distance="' . $distance . '" 
    GROUP BY user_id 
    ORDER BY min(recorded_time) ASC
'));
```

Comment: Your problem is not really clear to me. What *exactly* you want to return?

Comment: Ive updated my post.... All i want it to do is group the query by the user_id column and take the fastest recorded_time where the stroke column = fly

Comment: Can't you use `min(recorded_time)`? See [this](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#aggregates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's raw query as I don't know laravel syntax

```
SELECT `user_id`, `race_id`, min(`recorded_time`) AS `recorded_time`, `stroke`
FROM `race_history`
WHERE `stroke` = 'fly'
GROUP BY `user_id`
ORDER BY `recorded_time` ASC
```